# How to do color printing in HPBasic

Tags: printing, drivers, basic

Since yesterday, i'm trying to do color printing but it's not working.
Can someone send me an example to print something in colors.

I tried this :

```
   PRINTER IS 26
   PLOTTER IS 26,"HPGL;PCL5;COLOR,1600",0,260,0,185
   PRINT "*** TEST ****"
   FOR Numloop=0 TO 25
     PRINT PEN Numloop
     PRINT "*";Numloop
   NEXT Numloop
   END
```

But still printing black and white.
Thank's